# How to stop the flickering of recyclerview when called the api in handler

Tags: php, android, sql, api, android-recyclerview

I am new to android and I am trying to call the api after few seconds to get the updated data and set that data using Volley to recyclerview containing imageview,But after adding the api method in handler the recyclerview images keeps on flickering.So It will be very helpful if anyone could solve the issue.

```
                    handler = new Handler();
                    //   final Runnable r = new Runnable()
                    r = new Runnable()
                    {
                        public void run()
                        {
                            if(!handlerStop){
                                //
                                boolean flag = hasConnection();
                                if (flag) {

                                    String 
        url1=AllUrl.WHOS_CHECKIN+loginUserId+"&club_id="+clubId;
                                    String url12=url1.replace(" ","%20");


                                    handler.postDelayed(this, 2000);
                                    whosGoingDetails(url12);


                                } else {
                                    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);

                                }



                            }

                        }
                    };
                    handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
```

//whosGoingDetails method:

```
public void whosGoingDetails(String url){

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.d("whoscheckin_response", response.toString());

            try {
                // Parsing json object response
                // response will be a json object
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response.toString());
                String res = object.getString("response");
                if(res.equals("200")){
                    JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("message");
                    if(array.length()==0){
                        goingRel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    else{
                        usergoingList = new ArrayList<>();
                        goingRel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        for (int r = 0; r < array.length(); r++) {
                            JSONObject object6 = array.getJSONObject(r);
                            UserGoingModel model = new UserGoingModel();

                            String user_id = object6.getString("user_id");
                            String user_age = object6.getString("user_age");
                            String user_gender = object6.getString("user_gender");
                            String user_photo = object6.getString("user_photo");
                            model.userId = object6.getString("user_id");
                            model.userAge = object6.getString("user_age");
                            model.userGender = object6.getString("user_gender");
                            model.userPhoto = object6.getString("user_photo");

                            usergoingList.add(model);

                        }
                        goingAdapter = new UserGoingAdapter(usergoingList, ClubEventDetails.this);
                        goingRecycler.setAdapter(goingAdapter);



                    }
                }else{
                   // Toast.makeText(ClubEventDetails.this,object.getString("message"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }



            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d("main", "Error: " + error.getMessage());


        }
    });

    // Adding request to request queue
    jsonObjReq.setShouldCache(false);
    MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
}
```

Adapter:

```
    public class UserGoingAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserGoingAdapter.MyView> {
    private List<UserGoingModel> arrayList;
    private Context context;
    UserGoingModel current;
    private boolean isChecked;
    public String favClubUrl;
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "LoginPrefs";
    public static String loginUserId,loginUserMode,loginUserType;

    public UserGoingAdapter(List<UserGoingModel> arrayList, Context context) {
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public UserGoingAdapter.MyView onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.usergoing_row, parent, false);
        MyView viewHolder = new MyView(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(UserGoingAdapter.MyView holder, int position) {
        sharedpreferences=context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        loginUserId=sharedpreferences.getString("user_id","");
        loginUserType=sharedpreferences.getString("user_type","");
        loginUserMode=sharedpreferences.getString("mode","");

        current=arrayList.get(position);
        String user_id=current.userId;
        String user_age=current.userAge;
        String user_gender=current.userGender;
        String user_img=current.userPhoto;

        if(user_img.equals("")){
            Picasso.with(context.getApplicationContext())
                    .load(R.drawable.profile)
                    .into(holder.profile_img);
           // holder.profile_img.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.profile));

        }
        else{
            Picasso.with(context.getApplicationContext())
                    .load(current.userPhoto)
                    .into(holder.profile_img);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null != arrayList ? arrayList.size() : 0);
    }

    public class MyView extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        //public ImageView profile_img;
        //public CircularImageView profile_img;
        public CircleImageView profile_img;
        public MyView(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            profile_img=(CircleImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_profile);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code I am using to call to method after some time.

Comment: Post your entire class/activity